# Easy way to decode mp3 into wav programmatically?

Tags: cocoa, macos, mp3, wav, qtkit

Is there an easy way to convert mp3s to wavs on a mac (programmatically) with (maybe with QTKit)?
I've seen the SoundConvert example but to be honest I just don't understand it :P
I need it to pass it to libofa for audio fingerprinting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! I leave it here, somebody might find it useful.

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *inputFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"./in.mp3"];
NSString *outputFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"./out.wav"];

QTMovie *movie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:inputFile error:&error];

if (error) {
    #warning handle errors
}

NSDictionary *exportAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], QTMovieExport,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithLong:kQTFileTypeWave], QTMovieExportType, nil];


if (![movie writeToFile:outputFile withAttributes:exportAttributes]) {
    #warning handle errors
}
```

Comment: Exactly i am looking for, but deprecated :(